# LINQ Dynamic Where - Not adding clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
public OTestTable GetTestCode(Func<TestTable, bool> whereClause)
{
    return CoreContext.TestTables.Where(whereClause).Select(TestTableMap.DataToObject).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

CoreContext is my data context (which is initialized in a base class)

My TestTableMap is as follows:

```
public class TestTableMap
{
    public static readonly Func<TestTable, OTestTable> DataToObject = mapper =>
       new OTestTable
       {
           Code = mapper.mycode 

       };
}
```

Then in my business method i have the following:

```
public OTestTable GetTestCode(string code)
{
    return QueryEngine.GetTestCode(id => id.mycode == code);
}
```

From my main program, i am calling GetTestCode with a string value.

When I watch SQL profiler, I get the following:

```
SELECT [t0].[mycode]
FROM [dbo].[TestTable] AS [t0]
```

It does not have the where clause appended to the SQL query. If i add the where clause to the LINQ as var query = from c in DataContext.TestTable where c.mycode == '' select c;

It will add the where clause.

However, when I run my code, it will return the correct record, but it seems like I am pulling back all records from the database and filtering in my code (which should not happen).

Any thoughts with what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to construct SQL statements, LINQ to SQL requires an expression tree. `Func<TestTable, bool>` does not represent an expression tree, it is a "black box" function pointer. LINQ cannot do anything intelligent with this apart from blindly execute it on an in-memory collection.

You need to do this instead:

```
public OTestTable GetTestCode(Expression<Func<TestTable, bool>> whereClause) {
    return CoreContext.TestTables.Where(whereClause).Select(TestTableMap.DataToObject).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This code compiles using the `Queryable.Where` extension method, which does accept an expression tree, rather than the `Enumerable.Where` extension method, which only accepts a raw delegate.

Comment: that was it!! I totally forgot about using the Expression!! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Try creating your where clause as:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereClause
```

Where the T parameter is your source type `Table<T> source`

Answer (score 0):

Also see the `PredicateBuilder` here: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

It provides you convenient extension methods to predicate `IQueryable<T>`. like this:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Family>();
predicate = predicate.And(o => o.Birthday < new DateTime(1980, 1, 1));
                     .Or(o => o.Name.Contains("ke"));
var result = Source.Where(predicate).ToList();
```